# Stretch navigation bar to full width using uikit

Tags: javascript, html, uikit

I know that this can be done if the navigation bar used basic html. How can the navbar be stretched to the full width using uikit ?
My navbar code :

```
<nav class="uk-navbar">
        <a href="#" class="uk-navbar-brand">Web</a>
        <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just reproduced your example and it's working fine: http://codepen.io/untmat/pen/JKgZLw

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.26.4/css/uikit.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.26.4/css/uikit.min.css"></script>

<nav class="uk-navbar">
  <a href="#" class="uk-navbar-brand">Web</a>
  <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Maybe you haven't added **uikit.css**, **jquery.js** and **uikit.js** properly?

Comment: @XYZProgrammer - I've tried & I'm getting the exact same result.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I had <div class="uk-container uk-container-center"> surrounding my navbar tag. Thanks a lot.